# Use get input in the browser with Python

Tags: python, api, http, soap, httprequest

I would like to know how can I do an http request and receive the value of a specific function.
For example:

Request:: `http://192.168.1.1:8080/sum?number1=X&number2=Y`

Answer: **X** + **Y** = **W**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) utility to do what you would like.

```
import requests
url = "http://192.168.1.1:8080/sum?number1=X&number2=Y"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.text)
W = response.text
```

Note: This example assumes that the response information you want comes back as the value of the page and is not needing to be decoded.  Also note, W will be returned as a string so you may need to perform verification and type checking on it before using it.